# Django CharField add to choices from front-end

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-orm

#### Problem Description

Suppose I have a model with a `CharField` that has choices as follows:

```
class MyModelWithChoice(models.Model):
    FIELD1_CHOICES = (('1', 'One'),)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_lenth=32, choices=FIELD1_CHOICES)
```

Is there a way to add to these choices from the front end?

#### Preventing the problem

I know that the problem can be prevented by creating another model and using a `ForeignKey` for `field1`, which works just fine.

#### Reason I'm trying to find another way

The reason I'm trying to avoid creating a new model is because it doesn't really carry any more information. If it contained further information about the choice, I wouldn't have a problem, but it seems like too much overhead to create a table in the db just for the choices

Comment: Normally the ideas of choices are that thes are *static* ones.

Comment: Relational databases loooooooooooove having a table just for the choices. That allows you to store the foreign key value in your transactional table and keep referential integrity

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use **django forms** then you can use django forms in your **fron-end**

See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) documentation from django offical website

Comment: I understand. django forms use the choices specified in the model, I'm taking about adding to those choices without needing a dedicated database table for the job. I think the comments on the post pretty much sum it up

Comment: @robotHamster So why you don't use **select** field in front-end?

Comment: @robotHamster If you use select field and defin your specified choices in front-end you can add theme to database without needing to specify choices in modal

Comment: That still means that I need to deploy an update to the website each time I want to update the choices... I think the comments on the question directly address the issue